# can not create c++ project using NetBeans IDE, build host not connected

Tags: netbeans

I'm new to C++ and is trying to use the NetBeans IDE to create a C++ project. However, I have encountered the following error. I have downloaded the sygwin compiler but after mending around for a hour and half, I still couldn't get the NetBeans C++ compiler working? Could someone please give me a hand? I apologise if this sounds silly to some of you. Thanks in advance for any help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The NetBeans C/C++ bundle does not include a C/C++ compiler.
You have to download an environment like Cygwin or MinGW which includes the compiler and then add it as build host.

https://netbeans.org/community/releases/72/cpp-setup-instructions.html#compilers_windows